# Finding the location of the subgrid

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

[image]I have a $9*9$ grid and that grid consist of $ 9$  $   3*3$ subgrids , as shown in attachemnt, say that i have an index variable at 22 as marked in red , what is the formula to calculate so that i get a value 1 which is number of first subgrid because indexes are started from 0.?

Comment: yes , sorry i edited that :(

Comment: Is this a sudoku puzzle? And do you want to know which number goes in the marked square according to that puzzle?

Comment: yes i am trying to create a program but i can't find a formula to find a subgrid and 22 is index not the domain value. i could find the formula for row and colums and aslo linearization from two dimensions to one but can't find the number of subgrid :(

Comment: if my index variable has value 22 then does that value fall in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 or 9th subgrid?

Answer (score 0):

To find the 3x3 square in which $x$ in a 1D list representation of your grid lies, you need to compute

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\text{mod }(x,9)}{3}\right\rfloor+3\left\lfloor\frac{x}{27}\right\rfloor\text{.}$$

The square labeled $22$ is in the 1st grid, and plugging this into the formula gives

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\text{mod }(22,9)}{3}\right\rfloor+3\left\lfloor\frac{22}{27}\right\rfloor$$

$$=\left\lfloor\frac{4}{3}\right\rfloor+3\left\lfloor\frac{22}{27}\right\rfloor$$

$$=1+3(0)$$

$$=1$$

as expected.

If you are writing a program, however, I advise you to use a 2D array. This is defined in almost every language.

In C++ for example, one could define your array to be:

> int grid[9][9];
>
> grid[4][4] = 34;
>
> std::cout << grid[4][4] << std::endl;

This program initializes a 9x9 grid, sets the value in the 5th row and column to 34, then outputs that to the screen.

To directly answer your question, in a program, the value of the 3x3 grid a certain square is in is simply

> (x % 9)/3 + 3 * (x/27)

if you are using a language that doesn't automatically do flooring of division. In Python 3, for example, you would have to write

> math.floor(x % 9)/3 + 3 * math.floor(x/27)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the solutions @Calconym btw i am trying to program in prolog with constraints so i don't have much choices :(

Comment: Whoa I've never learned about functional programming before! Wish you luck.